# iphone: displaying small, live camera image in window

Tags: iphone, camera, subview

I'd like to invoke the camera and display a live image in a small preview window (similar to below) that is embedded in a standard viewController.  The code below creates the live reduced camera image, but I cannot see the other objects on the NIB file. Thoughts appreciated.

[image]

```
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
//Setting the control source type as the Camera device.
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

//Camera display is off
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
imagePicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;

//Picking only the rear camera.
imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;

//Turning the camera flash off.
imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;

// Make camera view partial screen:
imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(imagePicker.cameraViewTransform, 0.5, 0.5);  

// add subView
[self.view addSubview:imagePicker.view];
[imagePicker viewWillAppear:YES];
[imagePicker viewDidAppear:YES];

// Show the picker:
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without running the code, it looks like you are changing the live image, not the size of the view. So the original fullsize view is showing over the top of your other views.

Have you tried using camerOverlayView to overlay the viewcontrollers view on top of the live image?

> cameraOverlayView
>   The custom view to display on top of the default image picker interface.
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *cameraOverlayView Discussion You
>   can use an overlay view to present a custom view hierarchy on top of
>   the default image picker interface. The image picker layers your
>   custom overlay view on top of the other image picker views and
>   positions it relative to the screen coordinates. If you have the
>   default camera controls set to be visible, incorporate transparency
>   into your view, or position it to avoid obscuring the underlying
>   content.

Comment: Thanks KB.  I'll try that idea.

Comment: @Jeremy have you found a solution? Have you posted a new question?